# how to create a cloud service package (.cspkg) and cloud service configuration file (.cscfg)

Tags: azure

I have created a web role locally, but I am struggling to do this with the windows azure sdk, the manuals dont seem to give clear instructions on how?

Thanks

Answer (score 18):

In Visual Studio, go in the *Solution explorer* panel,  right-click on your *Azure project* and click on *Package* function. A process will generate the cspkg and cscfg files.

Comment: Would you know how to solve this issue for cspkg file larger than 200MB?

Answer (score 8):

To create the .cspkg and .cscfg via MSBuild arguments:

```
/t:Publish /p:TargetProfile=Local /p:AutomatedBuild=True
```

or

```
/p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:TargetProfile=Local /p:AutomatedBuild=True
```

Remember to replace the TargetProfile with your actual desired profile. This will automatically pick up the right `ServiceDefinition.profile.csdef` file.

Comment: In the TFS Online Build Definition I also had to provide an OutputPath argument

Answer (score 7):

You have two options with Azure:

**Build your package and upload it through the Azure portal** https://manage.windowsazure.com/

1. In your Cloud project in Visual Studio right click and select "Package".
2. Select the service configuration and build configuration (Release, Debug) you want to package. Then hit on Package. This will build all the necessary projects for your cloud solution. Once finished, it will popup a window with 2 files: a cspkg and a cscfg. The cspkg can be opened with any zip software by the way.
3. Go to Azure portal. Select "Cloud Services". Select your cloud service name.
   Click on "UPLOAD A NEW PRODUCTION DEPLOYMENT". Select your cspkg and cscfg files form step 2. Give a name to your deployment.

You're done.

**Publish from Visual Studio.**
To save the hustle right click on your Cloud project and select "Publish". Apply the necessary settings (Cloud service -this will populate automatically-, Environment, Release...as in the previous way. Make sure you go to Advanced settings to select the correct storage account if you got multiple. Hit Next, and the Publish. Visual Studio will do all the hard work for you.

Comment: Would you know how to solve this issue for cspkg file larger than 200MB?

Answer (score 4):

Publishing from the GUIs (Azure Portal and Visual Studio right-click "Publish...") is fine to get started.

Eventually (sooner better than later) you'll want a reproducible scriptable one-button maker.

From within a Powershell script, the command **Publish-AzureServiceProject** is used to build the .cspkg and upload it. (I hesitate to say more; you'll get better results by scrutinizing their documentation, alas!)

Answer (score 2):

In Visual Studio Team Services you can produce the package as follows:[image]
The service configuration file is called "ServiceConfiguration.Cloud.cscfg" in this example. Ofcourse you can always use variables like $(BuildConfiguration). As platform I needed to use "anycpu" without a space, I was not able to get it working by using "any cpu".