# Build Errors that only appear when building with Rider or resharper build

Tags: c#, azure, visual-studio, rider

### Update:

I just got the same build errors using reSharper build, and after switching to vs build the code builds successfully. So this is not just related to Rider anymore, and I'm updating the title. I have found this ticket on youtrack, this issue remains unresolved for 7 years!
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-450390

I have recently tried to switch from visual studio to Jetbrains Rider. However a bunch of projects in my solution have generated build errors and are not detected in the Edit configuration when I try to launch them.

Here are the projects in question:

[image]

The build errors are all of this type (one for each project):

Microsoft.WindowsAzure.targets(383, 5): [WAT200] No default service configuration "ServiceConfiguration.cscfg" could be found in the project.

The service configuration file in those projects is called ServiceConfiguration.Dev{i}.cscfg, i = 0, 1, 2 .....

The file is correctly referenced in the project file as well. I don't get any errors in visual studio.

Renaming the file and removing the .devi makes the build pass, but I still can't select this as a project in the Edit configurations menu. In visual studio, I can set this as a startup project and it launches an azurite emulator and other things. I usually start this project in conjunction with another one.

Now I don't fully understand what these projects really are, but they seem to contain azure configurations (duh). I also found this suspicious line in the csproj files of those projects:

```
<CloudExtensionsDir Condition=" '$(CloudExtensionsDir)' == '' ">$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v$(VisualStudioVersion)\Windows Azure Tools\2.9\</CloudExtensionsDir>
```

And I have an error in the the below line in serviceDefinition.cscfg:

```
<ServiceDefinition name="NoteDeFraisServiceAzure" xmlns="[http://schemas.microsoft.com/ServiceHosting/2008/10/ServiceDefinition](http://schemas.microsoft.com/ServiceHosting/2008/10/ServiceDefinition)" schemaVersion="2015-04.2.6">
```

it says: URI is not registered (Settings | Languages & Frameworks | Schemas and DTDs.

On my side I installed the azure plugin for jetbrains Rider. Are there any modifications I should do in order to get working ?Sorry for my limited knowledge of these projects, I am new to .NET and Azure and don't really understand how configurations work.

Also, other projects build and run correctly on rider (the .Net 5 WebApIs project for example)

Comment: Which `.NET version` are you trying to move from `Visual Studio` to `Jetbrains Rider` ?

Comment: the solution uses both .NET core and .NET framework, but the project with the problem uses .NET framework V4.7.2

Answer (score 0):

> No default service configuration "ServiceConfiguration.cscfg" could be found in the project.

The project is missing the `ServiceConfiguration.cscfg` file.

We need to add the `ServiceConfiguration.cscfg` in the project folder.

Check [how to create a cloud service package (.cspkg) and cloud service configuration file (.cscfg)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15618251/) to add the Service Configuration file.

> And I have an error in the below line in serviceDefinition.cscfg:

As mentioned in the [MSDoc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cloud-services-extended-support/schema-cscfg-file#service-configuration-namespace), check the `XML namespace` format.

The format of `xmlns` is invalid. Update it as below.

```cs
<ServiceDefinition name="NoteDeFraisServiceAzure" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ServiceHosting/2008/10/ServiceDefinition" schemaVersion="2015-04.2.6">
```

> it says: URI is not registered (Settings | Languages & Frameworks | Schemas and DTDs.

Even this error message says the `schema URL` is not in the correct format.

Thanks @[Khalid Abuhakmeh](https://www.jetbrains.com/dotnet/guide/tutorials/resharper-to-rider/getting-started-for-resharper-users/)
for providing the clear steps on migrating from `Visual Studio` to `Rider`.

Comment: As I specified in my answer, the project is NOT missing the cscfg file, however it is present with a different Name (and correctly referenced as well). Please re read the description.
For the uri part, it works fine with vs studio, so why not with Rider?
I think this is a bug with rider, it cannot detect when u rename the cscfg file.