# Microsoft Azure Publishing from Visual Studio

Tags: azure, visual-studio, azure-cloud-services, azure-storage-account

I'm trying to deploy an app (bot) from Visual Studio to Azure cloud Service (classic). I chose the subscription and the cloud service. Then, the process is prompting me to create a storage account and my existing storage account is not being shown in the list. When I try to create the new storage account, I'm getting the following error as shown in the screenshot.

[image]

For reference I'm trying to deploy the bot from [here](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-comms-samples/tree/master/Samples/V1.0Samples/LocalMediaSamples/AudioVideoPlaybackBot). I've tried multiple examples from the repo but getting the same results.

Answer (score 1):

The reason for the error is that the **storage account** you have created in the new portal is likely under the **resource manager deployment model**, but you are using **cloud service classic** which is still under the **classic deployment model**.

I got the same error when I tried in my environment.

- To resolve this, you need to create classic Storage account in the `Portal=>Storage account(classic)`:

[image]

or you can create using the command:

```
New-AzureRmResource -ResourceName "" -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName -ResourceType "Microsoft.ClassicStorage/StorageAccounts" -Location "South Central US" -Properties @{ AccountType = "Standard_LRS" } -ApiVersion "2015-06-01" -Force
```

[image]

- As mentioned in [official MSDOC](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/updates/classic-azure-storage-accounts-will-be-retired-on-31-august-2024/), Cloud Services Classic and Storage accounts is going to be deprecated completely, ***it is recommended to use Cloud Services extended support with Azure Resource Manager which allows to use your existing Storage accounts***. Refer [MSDOC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/azure/cloud-services-extended-support?view=vs-2022).

[image]

- Create ***Cloud Service(Extended Suppport)*** in Portal.
- ***Configure Storage account during Cloud Service creation:***

[image]

- Right Click on `Project=>Publish(extended Support)` in Visual Studio.
- Configure deployment with your cloud service:

[image]

[image]

- Deployed Successfully:

[image]

- Able to run the deployed application:

[image]

Comment: I tried creating a storage account (classic) as well but that it not shown in the dropdown when I try to select it. Its the same behaviour as before

Comment: Did you try with Cloud Services extended support?

Comment: When I try to create the cloud service extended support, I get this error: "A virtual network and associated subnets are mandatory for a cloud service (extended support) and should be defined in the network configuration section of the .cscfg file. Please click the 'Learn more about these pre-requisites' link above to learn more about this requirement."

Comment: I think the app that I'm trying to publish from the repo mentioned in my question is not built for extended support it seems

Comment: I'm now trying to publish the app from Visual Studio but it its stuck on this step for more than 40 minutes now: "Uploading 'C:\Users\path\microsoft-graph-comms-samples\Samples\BetaSamples\LocalMediaSamples\PolicyRecordingBot\bin\Release\app.publish\PolicyRecordingBot.cspkg' as 'PolicyRecordingBot-489ad8a8.cspkg' to storage account..."

Comment: Any idea why it might be stuck? @Pravallika KV Thanks

Comment: Is this with cloud service extended support?

Comment: Yes with cloud service extended support

Comment: what's the size of your .cspkg file?

Comment: Just checked and I don't have a .cspkg file. I only have .cscfg and .csdef files

Comment: You can create .cspkg file. Follow steps in [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15618524/19991670) answer.

Comment: My .cspkg file is around 53 mbs which is not that big I believe. But it gets stuck on uploading everytime with no errors.

Comment: This process takes time, but it won't get stuck.Is it still happening?